# visualvm history graph

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

Is it possible in visual vm to set memory, process/gc activity etc. graphs to shift in time without lowering x scale? When application starts that graphs look nice, but after some time they toughly compressed along x axis and it becomes cumbersome to see what actually happens in application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do several things:

1. Go to `tools>options` and change 'Monitored Host' and/or 'Monitored Data' to something smaller than default 60 minutes. 60 minutes mean that the graph will remember data for last 60 minutes.
2. You can close other tabs ('Heap', 'Classes', 'Threads') to make a graph bigger.
3. You can use  [Tracer Framework](http://java.dzone.com/visualvm-13) to display your data. Tracer framework allows you to zoom-in zoom-out collected data.

[NOTE: This answer was last updated in January 2016 to reflect changes in JVisualVM.]

Comment: I changed the Chart Cache to 20 minutes but I still see 60 minutes in the graphs. is there anything else to do there besides clicking OK on the Options dialog box?

Comment: looks like a restart of VisualVM is required for that change to take effect.  +1 for the Tracer Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

From VisualVM version 1.3 is Tracer framework accessibility in the plugins manager.

**Tools->Plugins** 
tab **Available Plugins** 
name **Tracer-Monitor Probes**

[VisualVM v1.3 news](http://java.dzone.com/visualvm-13)